# Why is the browser ignoring my CSS stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on the Odin Project Foundations course. The Etch-a-Sketch project.

I'm 10 minutes in, and I'm having a problem.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link type="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="app.js"></script>

  <title>Etch-a-Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Etch-a-Sketch</h1>

  <div class="header">
    <h6>Select a size:</h6>
    <button id="popup" class="btn btn-danger">Select</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container"></div>

  <div class="footer">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Black</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Random</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

When I open a dev server, everything is glued to the top left corner. In Chrome DevTools it doesn't show any of my CSS. There's a read-only "user agent stylesheet" that's seemingly over-riding my code.

Suggestions?

I'm new, so I thought I might be doing something wrong with flexbox, so I tried other display-types to no avail. Tried resizing the whole html element, which didnt work either. When I copy CSS into devtools, it works.

Comment: Have you checked the "network" section of your dev tools? `/styles.css` might not exist and maybe that's why it has no effect (yet).

Comment: Please let me know the URL you are using to access. CSS path depends on it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

Duh: I had <link type="... instead of <link rel="...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your styles.css is in the same folder and add a ./ before your path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

Try this. Hope it'll solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem. It looks like bootstrap is loading on the webpage but not my css file

Comment: Try changing the order of both.